# CSS Media query with condition?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am not sure how to ask this question exactly.
I am using jQuery to trigger animations on a nav bar (once you start scrolling, the nav bar becomes smaller - including the logo image inside). Everything works great. There is an "in" and an "out" animation.

My problem is that I have a CSS media query that reduces the logo image size at 1200px. The "in" and "out" animations include actual sizes that don't take the screen size into account. So, when the browser gets to 1200px, the logo reduces in size. BUT once the user starts scrolling and then scrolls back to the top, the jQuery "out" is triggered and the logo image goes back to original (full screen) size.

Is there a way to tell the jQuery script to go back to whatever the original size was?

Hard to present code since this is a large enterprise site, but here is the jquery and css media query...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var scroll = 0;
var target = $("#navtrip");
var offset = target.offset();

if (target.length) 
{
    $(document).scroll(function () 
    {
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (scroll > offset.top) 
        {
            $(".bg-dark").css({
                "animation-name" : "bgchangein",
                "animation-duration" : "600ms",
                "animation-fill-mode" : "forwards"
            });
            $(".nav-link").css({
                "animation-name" : "navchangein",
                "animation-duration" : "600ms",
                "animation-fill-mode" : "forwards"
            });
            $("#logoimg").css({
                "animation-name" : "logochangein",
                "animation-duration" : "600ms",
                "animation-fill-mode" : "forwards"
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(".bg-dark").css("animation-name", "bgchangeout");
            $(".nav-link").css("animation-name", "navchangeout");
            $("#logoimg").css("animation-name", "logochangeout");
        }
    });
}
});
```

and the css

```
@keyframes bgchangein
{
    0%
    {
        background-color: #13293D89;
    }   
    100%
    {
        background-color: #13293D;
    }
}

@keyframes bgchangeout
{
    0%
    {
        background-color: #13293D;
    }
    100%
    {
        background-color: #13293D89;
    }
}

@keyframes navchangein 
{
    0% 
    {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    100% 
    {
        font-size: 75%;
    }
}

@keyframes navchangeout 
{
    0% 
    {
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    100% 
    {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes logochangein 
{
    0% 
    {
        height: 56px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    100% 
    {
        height: 28px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@keyframes logochangeout 
{
    0% 
    {
        height: 28px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    100% 
    {
        height: 56px;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your window width via jQuery and then apply conditions to your navbar animations which apply different values depending on window width (or just apply the animation only above or below a certain width)

So that would be

```
var window_width = jQuery(window).innerWidth();
```

to get the window width, and

```
if(window_width > 1200) {
   [...] (your animation script here)
}
```

as a condition

Comment: It is always simple solutions. Thank you. Very obvious.